# Visual Studio Code - any way of highlighting different kinds of errors & warnings seperately?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

[image: Illustrating two different types of errors that are highlighted in the same way]

In the above image, there are two different types of syntax error - the `documents` one is a TypeScript issue and the other is an ESLint Prettier issue.

Does anyone know of a way/plugin that would enable the two to be styled differently? If I dig into the developer tools for the code view they're styled with the same CSS so there's nothing basic to hook into. Would love to be able to style the format issues in a more subtle way - sometimes if a whole block is temporarily upset you can't identify any specific error.

Answer (score 0):

The color is using for all error, so you can't do that.